# Multiplication of 1d arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

I have two 1d vectors(they can also be 2d matrices in some circumstances).
I found the dot function for dot product but if i want to multiply a.dot(b) with these shapes:

```
a = [1,0.2,...]
a.shape = (10,)
b = [2.3,4,...]
b.shape = (21,)
a.dot(b) and I get ValueError: matrices not aligned.
```

and i want to do

```
c = a.dot(b)
c.shape = (10,21)
```

Any ideas how to do it? I tried also transpose function but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Lets start with two arrays:

```
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> b
array([5, 6, 7])
```

Transposing either array does not work because it is only 1D- there is nothing to transpose, instead you need to add a new axis:

```
>>> b.T
array([5, 6, 7])
>>> b[:,None]
array([[5],
       [6],
       [7]])
```

To get the dot product to work as shown you would have to do something convoluted:

```
>>> np.dot(a[:,None],b[None,:])
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [10, 12, 14],
       [15, 18, 21],
       [20, 24, 28]])
```

You can rely on broadcasting instead of `dot`:

```
a[:,None]*b
```

Or you can simply use outer:

```
np.outer(a,b)
```

All three options return the same result.

You might also be interested in something like this so that each vector is always a 2D array:

```
np.dot(np.atleast_2d(a).T, np.atleast_2d(b))
```

Comment: I hope that it will be possible to just call simple .dot function because now i must distinguish the 1d vector and matrix.

Comment: @Cospel See my updated answer, it may be helpful for you. All it does is abstract away the if statements, but it can reduce your issue to a single line.

Comment: This might be possible if a and b are individually defined. As soon as we are working with matrices, this turns into a huge inconvenience. It will never look nice

Answer (score 1):

An even easier way is to define your array like this:

```
 >>>b = numpy.array([[1,2,3]])
```

Then you can transpose your array easily:

```
 >>>b.T
 array([[1],
        [2],
        [3]])
```

And you can also do the multiplication:

```
 >>>b@b.T
 [[1 2 3]
 [2 4 6]
 [3 6 9]]
```

Another way is to force reshape your vector like this:

```
>>> b = numpy.array([1,2,3])
>>> b.reshape(1,3).T
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Comment: That 3rd example is element-wise multiplication, not a dot product.  Either the result should be `[[14]]`, or the input should be `>>>b*b.T`