# Conversion between R and Python(indexing issue?)

Tags: python, r

I'm trying to convert this R function to Python. However, I am running into issues with the results being incorrect.

The R function in question:

```
construct_omega <- function(k){

    E <- diag(2*k)
    omega <- matrix(0, ncol=2*k, nrow=2*k)

    for (i in 1:k){
        omega <- omega +
            E[,2*i-1] %*% t(E[,2*i]) -
            E[,2*i] %*% t(E[,2*i-1])
    }

    return(omega)

}
```

This is my current attempt at porting the function to Python:

```
def construct_omega(k=1):

    E = np.identity(2*k)
    omega = np.zeros((2*k, 2*k))

    for i in range(1, k):
        omega = omega + \
            E[:,2*i-1] * np.transpose(E[:,2*i]) - \
            E[:,2*i] * np.transpose(E[:,2*i-1])
    
    return omega
```

In R, the result matrix is this:

```
> construct_omega(2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    0    0
[2,]   -1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    1
[4,]    0    0   -1    0
```

But in Python, the result is the 4x4 zero matrix.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you should probably explain the logic that you are trying to achieve

Comment: @mozway Ultimately, this is what I'm trying to compute: https://i.imgur.com/FwzIjKA.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is an edge case of matrix multiplication in numpy. You should consult the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52712688/understand-np-matmul-on-1d-vectors) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566515/multiplication-of-1d-arrays-in-numpy). Basically what happens is that you are doing a dot product and getting a scalar, not a matrix as you assume. The fix is to use [`np.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html). The other issue is the indexing that in python starts at 0 so you need to rewrite your code a bit.

```py
import numpy as np

def construct_omega(k=1):
    
    E = np.identity(2*k)
    omega = np.zeros((2*k, 2*k))

    for i in range(k):
        omega = omega + \
            np.outer(E[:,2*i], E[:,2*i+1].T) - \
            np.outer(E[:,2*i+1], E[:,2*i].T)
        
    return omega

construct_omega(1)
#array([[ 0., 1.],
#       [ -1.,  0.]])
```

and

```py
construct_omega(2)
#array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
#       [-1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
#       [ 0.,  0., -1.,  0.]])
```